# SSIS-Slowly Changing dimension--Nvarchar(MAX) ISSUE

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting a data conversion error when I try to load data from one SQL table to another SQL table, using SSIS.

The source table has a column with data type `nvarchar(max)`. The destination table has the same data type.  I keep getting conversion errors when I use the Slowly Changing Dimension component.

> Error: " Input column "des" (116) has a long object data type of DT_TEXT,  DT_NTEXT  or  DT_IMAGE which is not supported"

Please help

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e85c7363-d5ac-4c5e-b2fc-f3ef1570c015/slowly-changing-dimension-data-type-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: The SSIS SCD component is _LAME_. There are many reasons to not use it, and this is one of them. Are the tables on the same SQL Server? Solve your problem and get 100x speed increase by just writing a MERGE statement instead

Answer (score 0):

Use something else besides the Slowly Changing Dimension.  You can't use that component with nvarchar(max).